# How do I get pytest to write its errors to a log file?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pytest, python-logging

I'm using pytest 7.4.2 and Selenium to configure automated tests of a web application. I'm trying to get a nice log file out of the process which shows info-level statements for status updates and error-level statements when exceptions are encountered.

I've configured a pytest.ini file as follows:

```
[pytest]
log_cli = true
log_cli_level = ERROR
log_cli_format = %(levelname)s | %(message)s
log_file = log.txt
log_file_level = INFO
log_file_format = %(asctime)s | %(levelname)s | %(message)s
log_file_date_format = %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S
```

Within the tests, I'm using logging.info to give status updates. These are written to the log file as expected.

When an exception is thrown, pytest displays the resulting error in the CLI, along with a stacktrace. However, these are not written to the log file. If I call logging.error within the test script it's logged as expected.

My assumption is that pytest simply isn't logging the exceptions it encounters. Is there a simple way to get it to do so?

Example CLI output excerpt:

```
ipoint.py:42: Exception
------------------------------ Captured log setup ------------------------------
INFO     ipoint:test_reAssignIncident.py:25 Begin test - ReAssigning Incident
INFO     ipoint:test_reAssignIncident.py:29 Setup - Incident created with id #2207981
=========================== short test summary info ============================
ERROR test_reAssignIncident.py::TestReAssignIncident::test_reAssignIncident - Exception: User is not configured in users.ini
```

The corresponding log file:

```
2023-10-27 12:54:53 | INFO | Begin test - ReAssigning Incident
2023-10-27 12:54:53 | INFO | Setup - Incident created with id #2207981
```

And what I'd like the corresponding log file to look like:

```
2023-10-27 12:54:53 | INFO | Begin test - ReAssigning Incident
2023-10-27 12:54:53 | INFO | Setup - Incident created with id #2207981
2023-10-27 12:54:53 | ERROR | test_reAssignIncident.py::TestReAssignIncident::test_reAssignIncident - Exception: User is not configured in users.ini
```

Thanks for any help you can provide!